# Double router forwarding - devices on main network can't ping 2nd network

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

Have 2 routers:
Main router (ISP provided) network is 192.168.1.(2-100) and I have my 2nd router saved in the DCHP reservation as 192.168.1.10 .
In it's NAPT settings, I have the port for my VNC server forwarded to 192.168.1.10

Second router (also has enabled DCHP but disabled WLAN) with network 192.168.0.(2-100), has the same port forwarded to 198.168.0.4 (my PC IP), but CanYouSeeMe.org and trying to connect to the VNC server results into a time out.

The computer can connect to the internet and can ping both routers.
The main router (SAM-4F1F-TT-W-VC) is locked by the ISP and I don't have access to DMZ.
The second router (TP-Link 841N) becomes unresponsive if I disable it's DCHP server and requires a factory reset.
Device on network 192.168.0 can ping a device on network 192.168.1, but a device on 192.168.1 can't ping anything on 192.168.0
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your devices on 192.168.1.X don't know how to talk to 192.168.0.X devices, since they are not in the same subnet, they send the traffic to their gateway (192.168.1.1) which must not have a route statement to say to route it back to 192.168.1.10 (gateway to 192.168.0.X network). Basically your choices here are add a static route statement to the "main" router, or add a route on each network device that when they talk to 192.168.0.X IP's, it has to use 192.168.1.10 as it's gateway.

Comment: @acejavelin The "main" router has a "Access settings" page in which I can set dynamic or static IP addresses to a MAC address. I set a static one to my second router MAC, which resulted into a random IP (totally different from the local network or the public IP) popping next to it and having 3 choices for "type" - blank, "A" or "CNAME" with required host name(If anybody can explain to me what are those pls do). Set it to CNAME with random "host name" and now I can access my port!!! VNC logged right away.

Comment: You need to find "Static Routes" or something like that... You should be able to define an IP range or subnet, and the gateway to use like 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.10 or something like that. Honestly, few consumer home routers are capable of this.

Comment: You should disable NAT altogether in the second router. There's absolutely no need to make another NAT already within your home network. Double NAT is generally a bad idea. The second router should be just a normal router (no NAT) forwarding packets between networks. If your current router does not allow to disable NAT, buy another one that does allow it. Of course you have also to define appropriate static routes as @acejavelin said, but disabling NAT on the second router should be the first thing.